# Windows switching issue through Winium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, winium

I am automating an application where I have to click elements on next window after login through Winium . . Below is the issue that I am observing, which is making my scripts failed.

Login is a small splash screen , which opens and I entered the Username and password correctly and logged in successfully

After that another screen is open(containing further functionalities) , and i am able to locate the element , but when i tried to click it , it keeps in loading state for a long time , and never returns (I tried to keep it loading for atleast 30 minutes)

I tried using this (webelement is found , and line "the order button" gets printed but then no action is performed)

```
WebElement loginFrame = driver.findElementByClassName("name of class");

System.out.println("Click the Orders Button .............");

loginFrame.findElement(By.name("text")).click();
```

If anybody how to handle the switching between the windows or have any suggestions . Please let me know .

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))` did you try this ? I am not sure if this is same in winium

Comment: I tried the same , but for winium it does not work